# Count number after a special symbol in redshift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

I have a field value of which is of the following format:

```
GPU#nDisplays:Intel(R) Iris(TM) Graphics 540#1 Microsoft Basic Render Driver#0
```

Now in this i want a sum of values after '#'. For instance, in this case my sum will be 1+0 = 1.

How do i get that using Redshift SQL query?

I tried something like this to start with:

```
(regexp_count(REGEXP_SUBSTR (cpu_params,'GPU#n[^,]*'),'#[0-9]')
```

Comment: hey @akshay_rao did my below answer work for you? if so please accept as correct answer - if not please explain why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a Redshift python UDF for this

[Here is the AWS documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-python-language-support.html)

Important - you need to:

```
revoke usage on language PLPYTHONU from PUBLIC;
grant usage on language PLPYTHONU to group udf_devs;
or
grant usage on language PLPYTHONU to user youruserid;
```

Please excuse my non-pythonic python code - I am sure this could be improved.

Just replace "yourstring" with your test string and run the following in Redshift.

```
create or replace function f_sum_after_hash (s varchar(max))
  returns integer
stable
as $$
def f_sum_after_hash(input_string):
    parts = input_string.split("#")
    score = 0
    for part in parts[1:]:
        index=0
        for c in part:
            if c.isdigit():
                index+=1
            else:
                break
        if index >0:
            score+=int(part[:index])
    return score
return f_sum_after_hash(s)
$$ language plpythonu;

select f_sum_after_hash ('yourstring');
```

Comment: Thanks for your response @Jon. However, for the AWS redshift i use, we do not have option to write UDF. I am trying a similar option by using a python script on the dump

Comment: All versions of redshift have that udf facility.

Comment: please see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/udf-security-and-privileges.html. I have added that step to the answer.